# Unit testing a class with EF Core and in memory Sqliteprovider - stack overflow error in a test runner

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, ef-core-3.1

I'd like to write a unit test for my service and I use in memory Sqlite database provider for this purpose, however, I am getting stack overflow error in a test runner while trying to add some entities to a DbContext.
The issue does not occur while reading from the DbContext.

The test code:

```cs
public class DbBoardGameServiceTest : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly TestDbFactory _testDbFactory;
        private readonly BoardGamesDbContext _dbContext;
        private readonly Mock<IMapper> _mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
        private readonly DbBoardGameService _sut;

        public DbBoardGameServiceTest()
        {
            _testDbFactory = new TestDbFactory();
            _dbContext = _testDbFactory.CreateDbContext();

            _sut = new DbBoardGameService(_dbContext, _mapperMock.Object);
        }

        [Fact(DisplayName = "All BoardGames from a database are returned after being mapped when service gets all board games")]
        public void All_BoardGames_from_a_database_are_returned_when_after_being_mapped_service_gets_all_board_games()
        {
            _mapperMock.Setup(mock => mock.Map<BoardGameDto>(It.IsAny<Models.BoardGame>()))
                       .Returns<Models.BoardGame>(boardGame => DtoWithName(boardGame.Name));

            _dbContext.BoardGames.AddRange(TestBoardGames); //this line causes stackoverflow
            var games = _dbContext.BoardGames.ToArray(); // this line does not cause any errors

            var actualBoardGames = _sut.GetAllBoardGames().ToArrayAsync().Result;

            var expectedBoardGames = new[]
            {
                DtoWithName("Name1"),
                DtoWithName("Name2"),
                DtoWithName("Name3"),
                DtoWithName("Name4"),
            };

            actualBoardGames.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedBoardGames);
        }

        private static Models.BoardGame[] TestBoardGames => new[]
        {
            new BoardGameBuilder().WithName("Name1").WithId(1).Build(),
            new BoardGameBuilder().WithName("Name2").WithId(2).Build(),
            new BoardGameBuilder().WithName("Name3").WithId(3).Build(),
            new BoardGameBuilder().WithName("Name4").WithId(4).Build()
        };

        private static BoardGameDto DtoWithName(string name) => new BoardGameDto(0, name, 0, 0, 0);

        public void Dispose() => _testDbFactory.Dispose();
    }
```

I'm completely lost, I've come across the information that stack overflow during tests might be caused by circular dependencies, but I doubt this is the case.
Any hints would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
It fails on Ubuntu 20.04, but on macOS it works fine.

Comment: Aside from circular dependencies, a stack overflow is also trivially caused by a method that ends up calling itself, either directly or indirectly, because some override or implementation isn't doing the right thing (such as can easily happen if your mock happens to not mock correctly). Inspecting the call stack (available in the exception details) should help.

Comment: It has something to do with adding entity to a dbContext. I've created the simplest possible test without any mocks where I only create the context and try to save an entity and it fails